# HP 8250 scanner

Tags: hp, scanner, xsane

I am running Ubuntu 20.10. I have an HP Scanjet 8250, which I dearly love when I can get it to work.

DocumentScanner drives the device, but returns a black (redacted?) page.

Xsane likewise drives the device, but complains "Backend sends more image data than defined in parameters" when I 'Acquire Preview', shows the page scanned, then locks up and refuses to do anything else until I reboot.

Thanks.

HPLIP does not see the ScanJet, even though it is plugged into the USB port directly. But Xsane finds it.

Comment: please [edit] your question to include details of what you did to install the printer including HPLIP and the research you have done.

Comment: I've faced issues with HPLIP on my DeskJet InkAdvantage 2135 on Ubuntu 20.x like random crashes etc. Let us know the version of HPLIP on the device. How did you install?

Comment: I had to install gdebi and alien prior to xsane to get mine to work (a couple of years ago)... Cannon scanner though.

Comment: I installed HPLIIP through Synaptic. It's version 3.20.5+dfsg0-3build1.

Comment: It seems that sane used to accommodate this scanner in avision.conf, but it's not there now.
I tried adding 'usb 0x030f 0x0b0f' there, to no avail.

Comment: man sane-avision(5) refers to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-avision.so".
I have a "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-avision.so.1"

Comment: With all my tinkering, including a reinstall of all things sane, Xsane no longer finds the 8250. But sane-find-scanner still does.

Comment: sane.project.org latest (?stable) release is 1.0.31. It has code that refers to avision and hp 8200 series (0x03f0:0x0b01 - that's mine!).
I downloaded the .zp. It must be compiled.
Can someone point me to a tutorial on how to install it?
Should I remove all things sane before I install this version? - Thanks.

Comment: Digging a little more...
I have an old tower system that runs 18.04.2. It _can_ run my hp 8250.
It has libsane1-avision.so.1.0.27.
How can I revert to sane 1.0.27 on my laptop's 20.10?
Anyone?

Comment: This morning I applied some updates that Synaptic suggested. Among them I noticed sane-hpaio, or something like, so I tried my scanner again.
So now scanimage -L sees the printer, as does Xsane and Simple Scan.
Simple-scan still gives me a totally redacted page.
Xsane does scan. That's great. However, if I try 'Acquire preview' it complains 'Backend sends more image data than it defined in parameters.' and locks up. I have to unplug the scanner from power and replug it in to see it again.
Well at least it's usable again.